# Custom scale in d3

Tags: d3.js

There are lots of scale functions in d3 (e .g.: d3.scale.linear(), d3.scale.sqrt(), d3.scale.log(), ...). But for a specific situation I need a different scale function (to be precise "[generalised logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function)"). Is there any way to define a custom scale function in d3? Like

```
function d3.scale.mycustom() {
       ...
}
```

It is easy from a mathematical point of view, but how do I implement this in d3?

With the hint of Enche, I tried the following:

```
var my_custom_scale = function interpolate(t) {

    var A  = 0;
    var K  = 1;
    var B  = 10;
    var NU = 0.7;
    var Q  = 0.5;
    var C  = 1;

    return A + (K - A) / Math.pow(C + Q * Math.exp(-1 * B * (t - 0.5)), 1 / NU);

}
```

Which works:

```
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.0)); // 0.0021
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.1)); // 0.0084
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.2)); // 0.0324
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.3)); // 0.1098
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.4)); // 0.2934
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.5)); // 0.5603
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.6)); // 0.7857
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.7)); // 0.9107
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.8)); // 0.9655
console.log(my_custom_scale(0.9)); // 0.9871
console.log(my_custom_scale(1.0)); // 0.9952
```

But how do I now make this available as `d3.scale.my_custom_scale`?

Answer (score 2):

That Wikipedia article is a little overwhelming to me to write the actual code, but:

> Is there any way to define a custom scale function in d3?

Yup! See [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). You might want/need to use an [interpolator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_interpolate), which you'll see referenced on the quantitative scales page often.

Comment: Enche, thanks so much. I tried your hint concerning an interpolation function. But how do I build a real d3 scale function to be called as something like `d3.scale.my_custome_scale`?

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon [enche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142194/4213607), here's how you could define a custom scale using an interpolator:

```
var interpolatorFactory = function(a, b) {
    return function(t) {
        // Your custom scale function here, 
        // where you interpolate between a and b 
        // using the parameter t.
        return a * (1 - t) + b * t;
    };
};
var myScale = d3.scaleLinear().interpolate(interpolatorFactory);
// myScale is a standard d3 scale, so you can do 
// myScale.range([0, 5])
// myScale.domain([1, 3]) 
// etc
```